# wordpress has strange string all over the place, and admin panel runs out of memory

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently installed Wordpress, Buddypress, as well as some other plugins, and starting messing around. This was just the day before WP 3.2.0 came out, but I can't update, since my server doesn't run PHP 5.

So, on my WP dashboard, in my "Incoming Links", "WordPress Blog" and "Plugins" boxes, I get:

```
Allowed memory size of 25165824 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 62 bytes)
in /www/inbulgaria.org/rock/root/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php on line 14066
```

The line number is either 14066 or 14068, which don't point to anything suspicious. Needless to say, I haven't messed with that file, and I have no clue what it does, really. I can only admire its over 15000 lines of code.

Also, I've been having the string 'flo' appearing all over the place, including before my doctype. I did convert some of my ANSI-encoded PHP files to UTF-8, since my site is in Bulgarian, could this be it? I've never had much success with using UTF-8...

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with memory allocation for PHP on your server, you can follow the instructions here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP to fix the problem.

Comment: Well, my server isn't exactly mine, and I don't have access to PHP's configuration. Besides, in my relatively short experience with PHP, this error has always happened when there was something else wrong.

Comment: Did you attempt the instructions above? Many hosts will allow WP to alter the memory limit in that way. Besides that you would just have to go through the basics like have you installed any new plugins recently or changed any settings?

Comment: My bad, didn't really pay attention to the content of what you linked to until I had posted my comment. I did put it right under WP_DEBUG, and it didn't help.

After that, I turned WP_DEBUG on, and got a whole lot of this:

Comment: `Warning: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated - argument passed by value; If you would like to pass it by reference, modify the declaration of apply_filters(). If you would like to enable call-time pass-by-reference, you can set allow_call_time_pass_reference to true in your INI file. However, future versions may not support this any longer. in /www/inbulgaria.org/rock/root/wp-content/plugins/buddypress/bp-groups.php on line 2078`

Comment: Sure enough, disabling BuddyPress removed the errant "flo"s, too. I'll try and re-install it.